# oData Expand does not work for the last added entity

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api, expand

After I add a BillAccountList item, I tried to load all BillAccountList with the related entity set using OData expand like below:

```
IEnumerable<BillAccountList> items = from bi in container.BillAccountLists.Expand("Biller1")
                                                     where bi.BusinessEntityID == entityID
                                                     select bi;
```

But, the expand did not work for the last added entity. The below screenshot shows the Entity[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo5sV.png) includes the Biller1 but the Entity[2] has null for the Biller1.

[image]

If I re-run the application, the expand works fine.

Do I need any option for adding a BillAccountList item to make the expand is work right after the adding?

```
BillAccountList newBal = new BillAccountList();
                    newBal.Biller = billerID;
                    newBal.BusinessEntityID = s1.currentCustomerEntityID;
                    container.AddToBillAccountLists(newBal);
                    var serviceResponse = container.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Check your database, is there a related entity before you rerun the application?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The entity is in the DB. It seems it is a client side issue and I'm investigating.

Comment: I fixed the problem. After I declare the Container as the local variable in the method, it works. But I don't know declaring the container in each method is the right way. Any comments?

Comment: Did you refresh your query? Perhaps the list was populated before you added it.  Since defining it as a new variable would probably reload the list.